# Using the same item of a tab bar controller, is it possible to instantiate alternate views based on the value of a boolean property?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Between 2 user types, if  either of the users clicks on 'Item 1' of a tab bar controller, is it possible to direct to different view controllers depending on the value of a boolean property for that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, i think your user type coming from back end according to your id. So you can do something like below.

```
struct User {
 salesPerson = false
 // other properties
}

let user = User()
if user.salesPerson { // that means salesPerson is true
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SalesPersonViewController") as? SalesPersonViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
} else { // that means false so you can push other vc
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdminViewController") as? AdminViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thx, what if I've already used storyboard to add the tabbarcontroller and connected VCs to each tab bar item? Do I need to start over programmatically or is there some way I can apply the above logic to one of the tab bar items?

Comment: So in my TabBarController - on the storyboard it seems to only allow a 1 to 1 connection with a segue between a tab bar item and a view controller. What I need is to apply the above conditional logic to decide which of the two VCs it goes to on selection, but can't find where it would go in a storyboard set up?

Comment: you need to do it via code, just like i do with boolean value